# Time sync between ubuntu and windows

Tags: sync, time, ntp

Iam working as a linux admin. In our company we are using a ubuntu server with windows clients. The time in each clients are not same. Is it possible to sync time from ubuntu server with the windows clients ? Plz help

Comment: Yes, it is possible. ;-) Are you asking how to set up an Ubuntu NTP server, or how to have Windows clients sync to an Ubuntu NTP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This write up explains how to setup your **Ubuntu Server** as an **NTP Server** and how to configure your **Windows Clients** to use your server to sync their time.

Keep in mind that the instructions *may differ slightly because you haven't provided the specs of your Ubuntu Server*, but the principal will be the same:

[Network Time Protocol (NTP) Server and Clients Setup in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/network-time-protocol-ntp-server-and-clients-setup-in-ubuntu.html)

Additional information, specifically for Ubuntu 12.04

[NTP Server - 12.04](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/ntp-server/)

Comment: cat /etc/lsb-release   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS"......this is the spec

Comment: Did you try following the examples I provided in the links above?

Comment: i need some time. i will check it shortly. Thank for u r info

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install ntp

and that should do and then launch the Date and Time SubSettings from System Setting, choose the Change button and select the server in your region and Accept

`sudo service ntp restart`

and that should do. Then do a

```
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

and that's it. Unless you want to add it to your `/etc/rc.conf` and add these lines

```
(/etc/init.d/ntp stop<br>
until ping -nq -c3 8.8.8.8; then<br>
   echo "Waiting for network..."<br>
done<br>
ntpdate -s time.nist.gov<br>
/etc/initd/ntp start)&
```

Good Luck